# imagecopyresampled not selecting defined coordinates of image

Tags: php, jquery, image, crop, imagecreatefrompng

I've added a cropping feature to a social network CMS written in PHP called Sngine.
I added a jquery plugin so users can select the area of the image that they want.
I'm using imagecopyresampled to select the desired coordinates of the image, however something is going wrong and it doesn't work as expected, a lot of image is not copied over and the final output still retains the black background.

Below is the original image
[image: Original image]

This is the final output

[image: Final output]

I'm really not sure what i'm doing wrong here, a lot of tutorials use the same algorithm to get cropping done. The coordinates are being passed correctly from the crop plugin to the php script.

Below is my code

```
    <?php
/**
 * ajax -> data -> report
 *
 * @package Sngine
 * @author Zamblek
 */

// fetch bootstrap
require('../../../bootstrap.php');

// fetch image class
require('../../class-image.php');
// check AJAX Request
is_ajax();

// user access

user_access(true);
try {
    $x = $_POST['crop']['x'];
    $y = $_POST['crop']['y'];
    $x2 = $_POST['crop']['x2'];
    $y2 = $_POST['crop']['y2'];
    $width = $_POST['crop']['w'];
    $height = $_POST['crop']['h'];    

    $file_path = $_POST['crop_file'];
    $file_path = $system['uploads_directory'].'/'.$file_path;
    $file_path = '../../../'.$file_path;

    $image = new Image($file_path);
    $type = $image->get_type();

    //crop and resize image
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);

    switch($type) {
        case "image/gif":
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($file_path);
            break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
            break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
            break;
    }
    $src_w = imagesx($source);
    $src_h = imagesy($source);


    //imagecopy($newImage,$source,0,0,$x,$y,$width,$height);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$x,$y,$width,$height,$src_w,$src_h);



    switch($type) {
        case "image/gif":
            imagegif($newImage,$file_path);
            break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":
            imagejpeg($newImage,$file_path,90);
            break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":
            imagepng($newImage,$file_path);
            break;
    }
    imagedestroy($newImage);
    return_json(['file' => $_POST['crop_file']]);

} catch (Exception $e){
    modal(ERROR, __("Error"), $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Try dumping all the parameters you are passing to `imagecopyresampled()` and checking them against the dimensions of the image to see how reasonable they look.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah i did that and unfortunately everything looks in order.

Comment: What are the values please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell { x: "90", y: "62", w: "458", h: "243", ow: 800, oh: 450 }
ow and oh being the dimensions of the original image, w and h being the dimensions of the crop. x and y being x1 and y1